# Запуск конкретных установщиков с указанием пути установки без UI

Tags: exe, msi

Решил создать себе полезный скриптик, который будет цеплять нужные установщики из сети\облака и устанавливать их без моего участия. Хочу добиться как можно большей автономности, а для этого нужно заставить их, установщики, работать без UI, но при этом передавать им путь установки. Я встречался с таким возможностями в некоторых инсталлерах, но не знаю каким путём это было сделано. К примеру, для Sublime Text 3 нашёл аргументы  /SP- /VERYSILENT /NORESTART , но это просто тихая установка без указания пути установки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть пути для достижения моей цели?

Answer (score 0):

Для каждого типа инсталлятора это будут свои параметры.

Для *msi* можно попробовать так

```
msiexec /i <MSI_PATH> INSTALLFOLDER="C:\test\" /qn /norestart
```